# Can not find SQL database created using SQL Sever Management Studio Express

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a database using Microsoft SQL Sever Management Studio Express but I could not find it on my computer. I could not search it by name as well.
I need to copy it to App_data of my application, but how?

Comment: can you still see it and open it from Management Studio Express?

Comment: Did you perform a search for files named `*.mdf`?

Answer (score 3):

if you can still see the database in SQL Management studio and want to see where the data and log files are, simply execute this command:

```
USE <database_name>
GO
sp_helpfile
GO
```

Comment: I guess he doesn't even know the name of the db :)

Comment: then he does not deserve to be using SQL Server :D how can he connect to a db with a connection string without knowing its name?

Comment: mine was just a guess, don't know exactly. My guess, he will recognize the db when he sees it :) the problem is where the heck is the db?

Comment: Yeah, I figured that. but if you not use GO as you do on the 2nd line, we have to use exec :)

Answer (score 0):

Browse to below folder :

```
%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA
```

was it there?

> **NOTE:**
>
> This is the default folder for MS SQL Server Express database files (mdf and ldf files) and it
>   might not be the same for you if you changed it or create your db
>   inside another folder or disk.

**UPDATE**

run the following script :

```
USE [master]
SELECT * FROM sys.databases
```

Is it there?

Answer (score 0):

I would start with

```
select name, create_date from sys.databases order by create_date desc;
```

to get the names of the databases on that server. Than proceed with Davide Piras answer

```
USE <database_name>;

exec sp_helpfile;
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this to get all the fils and the databases that you have on your catalog:

```
Use master
GO

SELECT 
name AS [LogicalName]
,physical_name AS [Location]
,state_desc AS [Status]
FROM sys.master_files
```

if you see it then the catalog have it all you have to do is to restart the service